# How can I get directives to work when placed inside of dynamically loaded content?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have created a directive that works fine when placed on my main homepage. However, if I try to use the directive on content that is loaded via ajax, then it doesn't work. Why? Consider this directive that wraps the datepicker plugin:

```
var app = angular.module("app",[])
app.directive('datePicker', function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).datepicker(scope.$eval(attrs.datePicker));
    }
}
});
```

This works:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>...</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <input date-picker="{changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2000:2050'}"  type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

The solution found [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701331/how-apply-an-angular-js-directive-to-ajax-content) doesn't seem right for me since I will be loading very large templates into my page via an ajax call (or through `$stateProvider`). Somewhere on the newly loaded content I will have the following (the exact same tag from above):

```
<input date-picker="{changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: '2000:2050'}"  type="text">
```

But it no longer works. This happens with all of my directives. They work on my homepage, but once I start dynamically loading new content via ajax calls then the directives no longer work. I'm very new to Angular, so I would appreciate it if any responses would be put in beginners terms. Thanks for any responses!

Comment: How are you loading the dynamic content? Are you loading an external template and then putting it into the page via jQuery's .html()? If it is as i suspect, then the reason it doesn't work is because AngularJS is unaware of any change.

Comment: Sometimes I'm using an ``$ajax`` call via jQuery, but other times I'm just making a state change via angular-ui's ``$stateProvider``. In both cases I can't get my directives to work in the newly loaded templates. How can I make angular aware of these template changes?

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer of this question might solve your issue.

[AngularJS + JQuery : How to get dynamic content working in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771513/angularjs-jquery-how-to-get-dynamic-content-working-in-angularjs)

Comment: According to that solution I do this: ``$("#dynamicContent").html(
  $compile(
    "<button ng-click='count = count + 1' ng-init='count=0'>Increment</button><span>count: {{count}} </span>"
  )(scope)
);``. But where do I place this code? Also, I'm loading in massive templates, not just a single line of code. I'm perplexed as to how to get anything to work (directives, etc.) that is not in my main controller. Once I start ajaxing in data then nothing works. I have been unable to find any articles that give a simple explanation for how to get ajaxed content to bind in angular apps.

Comment: You must use $resource and fetch the data from your controller if you want to get data via ajax. If you do it outside of the angular scope, you have to tell angular that you updated the scope using $scope.$apply()